# If a RACSignal sends next can I wrap it in something which sends completed instead?

Tags: reactive-cocoa, racsignal

A very simple question and I'm overseeing probably a key method in RAC.

Say I've got this simple signal

```
RACSignal *signal = [[RACSignal return:@"hello"] delay:10]
```

How can I without changing above code create a new signal which sends `completed` when any value is passed (in this case `@"hello"` after `10 seconds`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Some alternativs

```
RACSignal *completeSignal = [[signal take:1] ignoreValues];
```

---

```
RACSignal *completeSignal = [signal flattenMap:^(id value) {
    return [RACSignal empty];
}];
```

---

```
RACSignal *completeSignal = [signal flattenMap:^(id value) {
    return nil;
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also just use `-take:` with a parameter of `1`:

```
RACSignal *originalSignal = [[RACSignal return:@"hello"] delay:10];
RACSignal *completesOnFirstValue = [originalSignal take:1];
```

If you don't want the signal to send a value before it completes, you can use `-flattenMap:` as in your response, or you can use `-takeUntil:`:

```
RACSignal *completesBeforeFirstValue = [originalSignal takeUntil:originalSignal];
```

(The `-takeUntil:` operator will cause the signal to complete when the trigger signal fires before the value is delivered.)